# Is there a way to change the binding of a usercontrol's button at runtime

Tags: mvvm

I am building a UserControl to show for errors and I am trying to make it more dynamic. The problem is that the "Yes" button will cause different workflows to be called based on the type of error.

Is there a way to change the binding of the button when I instantiate it or should I just pass my error number around and change the flow in one ErrorControlYesCommand?

Answer (score 0):

Expose on the surface of your UserControl two properties of type ICommand--YesCommand and NoCommand.  Then, whoever binds against this control can handle the result appropriately.